# delete duplicates from tables contain join

Tags: sql, join, plsql, duplicates, sql-delete

Hi i want to delete duplicates from a table like this:

[image]

I know to add row_number but I cant delete
here is my code:

```
select *
  FROM building C JOIN (
 SELECT * 
from (
      select A.*,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER ORDER BY 
      T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER) AS RN
      from building a join(
                        select T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER ORDER
                        from building  t
                        where t.sf <100 
                        group by T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER
                        having count(*)>1 )t
     on T.YEAR_MONTH = a.YEAR_MONTH, T.LOCATION = a.LOCATION ,T.OWNER = a.OWNER) a
      )a
on T.YEAR_MONTH = a.YEAR_MONTH, T.LOCATION = a.LOCATION ,T.OWNER = a.OWNER
where a.rn= 1
```

I try to add delete in the beginning but I am getting an error massage : "commend NOT PROPERLY ENDED"

```
 DELETE C
  FROM building C JOIN (
  SELECT *
from (
      select A.*,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER ORDER BY 
      T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER) AS RN
      from building a join(
                        select T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER ORDER
                        from building  t
                        where t.sf <100 
                        group by T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER
                        having count(*)>1 )t
     on T.YEAR_MONTH = a.YEAR_MONTH, T.LOCATION = a.LOCATION ,T.OWNER = a.OWNER) a
      )a
on T.YEAR_MONTH = a.YEAR_MONTH, T.LOCATION = a.LOCATION ,T.OWNER = a.OWNER
where a.rn= 1
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with a SQLFiddle for your table create, insert schema? And why `a.rn = 1 in DELETE query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question.
but you can just try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM building 
WHERE building.id in (SELECT building.id FROM ...{your query } )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just replace `SELECT` with `DELETE`. The `DELETE` statement has a very different syntax. Here is one option. It is using `rowid` because it's not clear from your code what the primary key column is for table `building`.

```
DELETE FROM building WHERE rowid IN 
(
SELECT c.rowid
  FROM building C JOIN (
  SELECT *
from (
      select A.*,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER ORDER BY 
      T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER) AS RN
      from building a join(
                        select T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER ORDER
                        from building  t
                        where t.sf <100 
                        group by T.YEAR_MONTH,T.LOCATION,T.OWNER
                        having count(*)>1 )t
     on T.YEAR_MONTH = a.YEAR_MONTH, T.LOCATION = a.LOCATION ,T.OWNER = a.OWNER) a
      )a
on T.YEAR_MONTH = a.YEAR_MONTH, T.LOCATION = a.LOCATION ,T.OWNER = a.OWNER
where a.rn= 1
)
```

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql) is a great blog with the different options on how to delete duplicate records